# HtmlAgilityPack - Append node

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I've been trying to append a new Node in Html using Html Agility Pack.

This is my sample Html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>
        </title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .csDBEB299A{text-align:left;text-indent:0pt;margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;line-height:14.65pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly}
            .cs15323895{color:#000000;background-color:transparent;font-family:Verdana;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="csDBEB299A"><span class="cs15323895">This is a sample</span></p><p class="csDBEB299A"><span class="cs15323895">&nbsp;</span></p><p class="csDBEB299A"><span class="cs15323895">&nbsp;</span></p><p class="csDBEB299A"><span class="cs15323895">Table name: Table 1</span></p><p class="csDBEB299A"><span class="cs15323895">&nbsp;</span></p><p class="csDBEB299A"><a name="_GoBack"></a><span class="cs15323895">&nbsp;</span></p></body>
</html>
```

The condition is if the innerHtml starts with `"Table name:"` a node should be appended.

For example i have this

```
<span class="cs15323895">Table name: Table 1</span>
```

It will become

```
<span class="cs15323895">Table name: Table 1<h2>This is h2 heading</h2></span>
```

And here is the documentation of how to append child using Html Agility Pack

```
https://html-agility-pack.net/append-child
```

And here is my code

```
                var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
                htmlDoc.Load(htmlFile);

                foreach (var item in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants())
                {
                    if (!item.HasChildNodes)
                    {
                        var text = item.InnerHtml;
                        var textTosearch = "table name:";
                        if (text.ToLower().StartsWith(textTosearch))
                        {

                            HtmlNode h2Node = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<h2> This is h2 heading</h2>");
                            item.AppendChild(h2Node);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

But i'm receiving an error when i save it to a file

```
        htmlDoc.Save(@"test.html");
```

And below is the error:

```
Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
```

I've searched for a solution but the solution suggested in other question doesn't work with my problem.

I have try and catch but it doesn't give me the line where it encountered an error. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants()` returns not only usual elements like `span`, `div` and etc, it also returns special `text` elements that represent any text inside of `html` elements.

You need to add child node to the `span` element. But you actually add it to the `text` element which is the child node of `span` element. For some reason `HtmlAgilityPack` fails if child element is added to the `text` element.

Thus, you need to remove `if (!item.HasChildNodes)` condition since the target element has child `text` element and exclude `text` elements. Something like this should work:

```
foreach (var item in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants())
{
    if (item.NodeType != HtmlNodeType.Text)
    {
        var text = item.InnerHtml;
        var textTosearch = "table name:";
        if (text.ToLower().StartsWith(textTosearch))
        {

            HtmlNode h2Node = HtmlNode.CreateNode(@"<h2> This is h2 heading</h2>");
            item.AppendChild(h2Node);
        }
    }
}
```